# What is difference between implicit and explicit?

Tags: meaning

I have seen these words all the time in IT/Computer programming.

Examples: "How to **explicitly** render a template" and "do not **implicitly** assign to the local variable".

I am dyslexic and hard time to interpret the meaning of both words.

Comment: Should google the two words and see the difference in definition, usage, examples and more.

Comment: Kris, thanks, but that is not the kind of an answer I was looking for. I was hoping someone to provide an easy answer and usage example. I am dyslexic and hard time to interpret the meaning of both words.

Comment: The phrase "implicitly assign to the local variable" is something from computer programming... Probably asking here will not help much.

Comment: Hi Martin, [implicit](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/implicit) and [explicit](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/explicit) in a general sense are both in dictionaries. If you are interested in a more specific meaning, you will be better off looking for a programming-related explanation. [Implicit/explicit type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Implicit_type_conversion) is one example where knowing the meaning of "implicit" or "explicit" is probably not enough to understand the programming concept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**explicit** means that it is expressly stated and made obvious -- overt/obvious/manual.

**implicit** means that it is not obvious, it is *implied*. hidden/assumed/automatic.

when i see "explicitly render a template", it usually means the request to render the template is there, as opposed to executed automatically and "implied to be executed".

"implicitly assign", I'm not sure exactly without more context, but the implication here is that the assignment is not explicit, it happens somewhere else, or by default....

in programming, implicit and explicit often carry a meaning which is almost exactly the same as 'automatic'(implicit) or 'manual'(explicit)

Let me know if that doesn't help